# How to pass more than 1 models

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller

My question is: how can I send more than 1 `@model IEnumerable<MvcMovie.Models.Movie>`?

For example - I want to send to View from Controler: `db.Movies.ToList()` and `db.Letters.ToList()`. How to send it?
And how to get separatly in my View: IEnumerable with Movies and IEnumerable with Letters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My question is: how can I send more than 1 @model IEnumerable?

By using a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public FooBarModel TheFooBar { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
}
```

and then having your controller return this view model to the view:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel();
    model.Movies = ...
    model.TheFooBar = ...
    return View(model);
}
```

and finally your view will be strongly typed to the view model:

```
@model MyViewModel
```

and you will be able to access its properties.

Comment: wow! thanks :) and how to work here `@foreach (var item in Model)` only with Letters or Movies?

Comment: Like this: `@foreach (var movie in Model.Movies)`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to just create a Wrapper class that contains `Movies` and `Letters` list.